# Fixing the priorities and killing them

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am writing a program that generates random priorities, processes (and their corresponding IDs) into a text file (processes.txt). So far, I have gotten the help to generate the random processes, but I am unable to generate the priorities and their I.Ds. Also, I have to figuire out how to kill them all when done.

```
echo "Generating random processes between 10 and 30"


min=10;
max=30;
range=$(($max-$min+1));
echo "these are the processes" >> processes.txt
shuf -n $range -e $(ps -Ao pid=) >> processes.txt
echo "these are the priorities">> processes.txt
shuf -n $range -e --{-20..19} >> processes.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

this may help

```
seq -20 1 19 | shuf -n $range >> processes.txt
```

Edit:  Check this for showing them together

```
for i in $(ps -Ao pid= | shuf -n $range)
do 
  echo $i $((-20 + RANDOM % 40)) 
done
```

Comment: It works! I'm sorry, I'm not very good at this, but does it also print the IDs too?